# Can't get Search box to work in App Inventor 2

Tags: android, search, box, app-inventor

No matter what I do the `ResponseLabel.Text` won't change after hitting the search button. The keyboard does hide after I hit the search button though.

My code for the search button is

```
When Search Button Click
  Call Search Box.Request Focus
  Call Search Box.Hide Keyboard
```

Code for Search Box is:

```
When SearchBox Got Focus/
  if/ is in list?/ thing/ Search Box.Text/
                    list/ get GlobalMetalList/
  then/ set ResponseLabel.Text to/ Check Metal Page
  else/ set ResponseLabel.Text to/ Not Found.
```

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your blocks. You can upload it into a service like https://imgur.com/. Then **edit your question** and provide a link to your screenshot ... You can try to move the blocks from the `GotFocus` event into the `Click` event...

Answer (score -1):

Move the blocks from the `GotFocus` event into the `Click` event

Comment: please provide more details to the OP

Comment: Yes it' a short answer, but it is an answer and was taken from the comment section above and converted to an answer, because it worked...

Comment: keep in mind that other people might come to this question looking for a detailed answer

Comment: @MauricioGracia [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)